# async/await catch rejected Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm just getting started with `async/await` and running into a problem.

I can do as expected:

```
async function x() {
  let y = await Promise.resolve(42);
  return y;
}
```

But when I reject a `Promise`:

```
async function bad() {
  try {
   await Promise.reject('bad');
  } catch(err) {
    err; //AssertionError: TypeError: (0 , _errorHandler2.default) is not a function
  }
}
```

How do I catch `rejected Promises` with `async/await`?

Comment: With all the possible names for variables and functions, do you have to use `bad` for two different things in the space of 7 lines in a communication setting when you're asking for discussion that might refer to specific points or lines?  That practice is just, well, `bad`.  The question and code could be improved by using unique names to facilitate discussion.

Comment: I've removed the variable shadowing. Thanks @WBT
I'm actually kind of stunned this question wasn't deleted long ago. It doesn't make much sense to me now. I believe this was some issue with the Babel transpiler at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What `bad;` alone is supposed to do? The error is caught as expected, you just don't do anything with it:

```
async function bad() {
  try {
    await Promise.reject('bad');
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

bad();
```

This outputs `bad` as expected. [Code here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=async%20function%20bad()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20try%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20await%20Promise.reject('bad')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20catch(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(err)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(err)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Abad()%3B%0D%0A).